# Compute Relative Frequency in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, frequency, bin

With :

```
dalist = {{379, 219, 228, 401}, {387, 239, 230, 393}, 
          {403, 238, 217, 429}, {377, 233, 225, 432}}

BarChart@dalist
```

[image]

I would like to compute / Plot the relative frequency instead of absolute count for each Bin for each condition.

Where :

```
{379, 219, 228, 401}
```

are the 4 bins count for one condition. So :

```
{379, 219, 228, 401}[[1]]/Total@{379, 219, 228, 401}
```

[image]

is the result I want to see of the first condition / first Bin, instead of the count itself.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Mathematics Q&A?

Comment: I don`t think so, since, it is the implementation in Mathematica I am asking for.

Comment: Got it, I misread Mathematica with Mathematics :)

Comment: @Jose a common mistake. We get a lot of guys trying to close questions based on this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it

```
BarChart[dalist/Total /@ dalist]
```

?

[image]

Comment: @Leonid I see your (currently) deleted answer. Perhaps you should undelete it, just to provide another way to do the same. I think there is something there for a novice (comparing two ways to do the same thing is one of the many paths to learn Mma)

Comment: @belisarius, Thank you + you forced me to work my functionnal programming skills : (#/Total /@ #) &@((Total /@ Transpose[AnglesBins[[#]]]) & /@ Range[4])   this was the reality of dalist !

Comment: A more efficient version of your code would be `#/Total[#, {2}] &[dalist]`

Answer (score 4):

belisarius beat me to it.

You might also want to explore `BarChart[dalist, ChartLayout -> "Percentile"]`

[image]

Comment: +1 for a `ChartLayout -> "Percentile"` option setting - I was not aware of it.

Comment: There was something about Mathematica I knew and you didn't? Wow, I am surprised.

Comment: I don't think any single person knows more than a fraction of mma. Besides, when I was learning Mathematica programming (about 5-6 years ago), I learned a lot from your excellent site.

Comment: Seriously? That is really nice to know. Ted Ersek put a lot of work into those tips. I keep saying I will revamp the site one day, but real-life job expands to fill available space.

Comment: Revamping it sounds like a great idea, but I think even in its present form it is very useful - most of the stuff there still remains valid and useful.

Comment: @Verbeia - Ditto on the usefulness of your tips archive! Also, for what it's worth, I think an ideal revision would be centered around building a package with Workbench---basically just re-authoring everything so it's automatically accessible via the documentation center. Maybe you could rig it so functions with available 'tips/tricks' would automatically alert users somehow. Stylesheets ain't my strength... dunno how difficult it'd be to add a docked cell to function pages by default... or maybe generate a popup?---then again, that would be sure to pi$$ people off. :)

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 Most of the tips on the site (the "Alternative Help Browser") were done by Ted Ersek, who stopped answering his email a few years ago. I could look into it, but I have a few other things I need to do before undertaking something like that.

Comment: @Verbia - Do you not have a current email, or is Ted just too busy? (He has posted to MathGroup fairly recently and I'm able to look up an email addy that way.) Send me an email if you want it. (my addy in profile) Also thanks for the clarification on the identity issue. :) Econ nerds unite!

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 I have emailed the address he uses for MathGroup several times over the years. But now you know my real name, you can work out why I haven't the time for revamping the site, even if I have a bit of time at home for hanging out here. I have redefined faffing around in Mma as a leisure activity.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is this:

```
In[13]:= #/Total[#] & /@ dalist

Out[13]= {{379/1227, 73/409, 76/409, 401/1227}, {387/1249, 239/1249, 
  230/1249, 393/1249}, {31/99, 238/1287, 217/1287, 1/3}, {377/1267, 
  233/1267, 225/1267, 432/1267}}
```

and chart it instead

Comment: +1 This was the approach I was in the middle of typing before I saw belisarius’ answer come up. Had to come up with an  alternative

Comment: And this is exactly what I came to from Belisarius`s on my own. Thank You so much, I think i am making progress !